# VS2015 hangs when project datasource window and form visual designer are open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I have 2 objects in my project and add them as project datasource, for example

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

then visual studio hangs the time I open a form's visual designer. I can browse through the datasource window only if a form's code window is opened.

The problem occurs only when there is a one-to-many reference as above. If for example I ommit the property Orders from class Customer I don't get the error. VS must fall in an infinite loop or something but it has no problem with it if the form's designer is not open.

Is there a workaround for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Some people suggested it was a "lazy loading" recursive error related to the "virtual" keyword.  As you suspected it is not handling the one-to-many relationship very well.  Some users reported luck by disabling the lazy loading feature.  I tried that as well as removing the virtual keyword and had no luck.  Ultimately what fixed this issue for me was installing update 2 ctp.  Here is another thread on this topic.

[Visual Studio Crashes on opening Data Sources window](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/afc3e1c9-220c-4be0-9e3a-13c53fc211c6/visual-studio-crashes-on-opening-data-sources-window?forum=visualstudiogeneral)